# MySQL lag() with default value previous row value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

Here is my sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa7b9a/2 .

How I can get with LAG() previous and current it this for March results?

```
SELECT p6 as Current,lag(p6) over (ORDER BY dt) AS previous_val FROM dobridol
WHERE  dt BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-30'
```

Also how I can set first value to have for previous_val last FEB result and then to go as per usual?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.  You have multiple rows in each month, so it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions - calculate LAG for whole table and after that filter results:

```
SELECT 
    p6,
    id,
    prev_val 
FROM (
  SELECT
    dt,
    p6,
    id,
    lag(p6) over (ORDER BY dt) AS prev_val 
  FROM dobridol
) tbl
WHERE dt BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-30';
```

[SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=b389e6219f6b4b07baf1bf50dcb15d82&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear.  Which value do you want from the previous month?

If you want the maximum value, you can use `max()` with a window frame specification:

```
select d.*,
      max(p6) over (order by year(dt) * 12 + month(dt)
                    range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                   )
from dobridol d;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ccedfc8c0dca895e3413fbeca636427) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: from the previous month last row value.

Comment: SELECT p6 as Current,lag(p6) over (ORDER BY dt) AS previous_val FROM dobridol
WHERE  dt BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-30' - THIS query is OK  running in your fiddle but I want to have last FEB result instead of NULL for first returned row